# BSOD on Win 7 Downgrade ASUS F551C Laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, bios, uefi, asus-laptop

I have an Asus F551C laptop that came with Windows 8.1.  I used GPARTED to remove the GPT partitions and then created an NTFS partition and installed Win7 with no problems.  I then ran updates and installed software.  After a reboot the system now boots to a BSOD stop code: 0x0000005.  When I try and run a repair from the Windows 7 DVD, it cannot find the drives. The BIOS does see the hard drive.

I have tried playing with the BIOS settings - changing from AHCI to IDE, enabling and disabling CSM, etc.  Nothing seems to work.

Has anyone else seen this particular issue?

Comment: "used GPARTED to remove the GPT" - Why did you do this then proceed to disable CSM?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and will tell anyone who has the same thing what i did.

in the BIOS enable CSM and the sub-item (I forgot the exact name), disable secure boot, then boot to a GPARTED live USB. Delete all partitions. Reboot to Win7 USB and install went fine.